how to resolve "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error in C++ VSCode
I'm trying to write some simple C++ code in Visual Studio Code, but I keep getting the error "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" whenever I try to make and call a class. Strangely, I do not get this error if I copy-paste my code into XCode, a different development environment I have used in the past. I tried deleting the various extra files VSCode generates in the project (such as tasks.json) so it will remake them, but the problem persists. I am using clang++ as my compiler. 
Here is some simplified code I wrote to try and troubleshoot the problem: 
main.cpp:
#include "main.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    testLink test = testLink();
}

main.hpp:
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

#include <iostream>
#include "testLink.hpp"

using namespace std;

#endif /* main_h */

testLink.cpp:
#include "testLink.hpp"

testLink::testLink()
{
    
}

testLink.hpp:
#ifndef testLink_h
#define testLink_h

using namespace std;

class testLink
{
    private:
    public:
        testLink();
};

#endif /* testLink_h */


Did you edit your tasks.json to have it build all of your c++ source files? Remember that the default behavior of VSCode is to attempt to build only the active file into an executable ignoring all other files. The official documentation explains this behavior here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson

If you're using VSCode, then I assume you're using the default coderunner plugin, which only tries to build the currently active tab. It will not build with all source files, which you need to do. Please read the VSCode C++ documentation, especially the parts that are relevant for your system (OS and compiler), and use the Microsoft C and C++ plugin instead.

Also when asking a question at StackOverflow that is about compiler errors you should always copy the text of the error messages and place that in your question as text (no pictures of text please). In this case you probably should have copied the entire build log showing the compiler command line that was executed.

Are you on windows? If so consider switching to "visual studio community edition" its is much more user friendly.  Anyway if you have multiple source files you need to compile them all and link them.

I expect that Lucas is using macOS because of the XCode mention.

The problem is that you think VSCode is compiling both your .cpp files (like XCode does) but this is not true. You should read the VSCode documentation on how to make this happen.
